# C# LINQ: remove null values from an array and return as not nullable

Tags: c#, linq

I'm converting nullable array to unnullable. This is my current code with two function calls:

```
myarray.Where(e => e.HasValue).Select(e => e.Value)
```

It looks like a very basic operation. Is it possible to do that in one call?

Comment: No, if you want to remove all null values (step 1) and then convert the results so to the underlying type where `Nullable<T>` is cast back to `T` (step 2) this is as good as it gets.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can always make your own extensions but that **only makes your code seem more succinct**, think that **your implementation is the most succinct and clear you can get** to be honest

```
public static IEnumerable<T> GetNonNullValues<T>(this IEnumerable<Nullable<T>> items) where T: struct
{
    return items.Where(a=>a.HasValue).Select(a=>a.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 19):

```
myarray.OfType<int>();
```

This works because nullable types box to their underlying types if they are not null, but don't if they are null.

EDIT: The only thing I'll point out is that the semantics of the one-liner I made are slightly different than yours. It could be that you'd want yours instead of mine. Your code: "grab all nullable objects which have a value". My code: "grab all types which can successfully be cast to int"

Comment: Perfect! That's what I was looking for.

Comment: The only thing I'll point out is that the semantics of the one-liner I made are slightly different than yours.  It could be that you'd want yours instead of mine.  Your code: "grab all nullable objects which have a value".  My code: "grab all types which can successfully be cast to `int`".

Comment: @DmitryPetrov This code involves boxing, type checks and unboxing operations for each element of the array, thus is quite inefficient compared to your original code. Never use this in production. Your code is just fine.

Comment: For what it's worth, there are still rough edges to nullability tracking (C# 8/.NET Core 3.1), and this approach avoids nullability warnings whereas the others don't.  Where performance isn't critical, it's nice to know.  Reference: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/37468#issuecomment-515142288

Comment: I want to confirm here that this does in fact work nicely with nullable classes with #nullable enable too. I wasn't sure if it would work with reference types that can traditionally hold nulls.

Answer (score 4):

try using [`.OfType(...)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913(v=vs.110).aspx)

Example...

```
myarray.OfType<int>()
```

... this worked for me ...

```
var d = new int?[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, null, null, 6, 7, 8, 9, null };
Console.WriteLine(d.Count()); // 12
Console.WriteLine(d.OfType<int>().Count()); //9
```

Comment: Great solution! I've accepted John's comment just because he was the first.

Comment: First in the list but I answered before him ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
myarray.Where(e => e.HasValue).Select(e => e.GetValueOrDefault()))
```

Comment: It is still 2 steps, I fail to see the advantage of this over what is in the question.

Comment: This is actually *less* efficient, and longer, than the OPs version.

Comment: Ok, you are right. I think I agree with Eli is the shortest way if you want to exclude null items.

Answer (score 0):

Your expression is as pretty as it can get, and thanks to how the `Enumerables` are looped through, your collection won't technically be visited twice in two separate loops.

If you still want to do it in a single expression, here is one of the many ugly ways.

```
myarray.Aggregate(Enumerable.Empty<YourElementType>(), (prev, next) => next.HasValue? prev.Concat(new [] { next }) : prev);
```

The above should never be used and it is only for demonstration purposes. I would use what you wrote in your question, yours is prettier.

Answer (score -1):

While `.OfType<>` solution works, the intent is not quite clear there, I suggest this solution that is pretty much the same that the solution in the question, but it allows compiler and e.g. R# to be sure in the output type and not have a warning for a possible null reference exception (for e.g. nullable reference types in C# 8).

```
myarray
  .Where(e => e != null)
  .Select(e => e ?? new Exception("Unexpected null value"))
```

This seems like a bit overkill, and can be fixed with e.g. "e!", but it's a bit more secure against future errors (if e.g. where clause is modified by mistake)

Comment: IMO the intent of checking for null twice and throwing an exception that on a closer look will never happen isn't clear either. Throwing an exception makes the code look very hazardous and is very distracting. I wouldn't construct code purely to make R# happy. Then at least use `GetValueOrDefault()`, even though the "default" part will never be hit.

Comment: It will not make R# happy, it will make compiler happy which is a big difference. Nullability inference unfortunately is not smart enough to figure out that there cannot be any non null entities in Select. Additionally Where clause can be changed in the future without someone understanding the consequences and then the exception will trigger.

Comment: An exception is overkill. Also, it doesn't compile. I can't seem to find in which exact circumstances the throw expression can be used with the null coalescing operator, but this case is not supported. I only get it to compile in C# 8 in a property setter evaluating the `value` parameter.

Comment: I am not sure which version of .net/C# you need to compile it, but the latest dotnet5/c# 9 compiles just fine. It's a new syntax introduced relatively recently. The type of enumerable should be nullable for that to work and you have to enable nullability.

Comment: Additionally `GetValueOrDefault` would not work as it will not "remove" the nullability. Maybe it's not very clear in the answer, but it is probably not as useful without nullable reference types on, but when you turn it on, it's not enough with other solutions.