# Is there any way to give compiler a hint about nullability in case of chained methods?

Tags: c#, nullable-reference-types

Consider type `Foo` and something which yields `IEnumerable<Foo?>`.

Later in code I do `seq.Where(x => x != null)`, so effectively it should become `IEnumerable<Foo>` for all other methods down the chain.

Is there an elegant way to let compiler know items are not `null` anymore?

Comment: Hmm, will `.OfType<Foo>()` filter out `null`s? Otherwise `Where(...).Select(o => (Foo)o)`.

Comment: Something like `seq.Where(x => x != null).Select(x => x!)`

Comment: I considered this option, but this is a real additional call at run time.

Comment: @Sinatr - yes, `OfType` will eliminate the nulls and change the type of enumerable.

Comment: You can write own extension method which will filter and cast in one iteration.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# LINQ: remove null values from an array and return as not nullable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38381612/c-sharp-linq-remove-null-values-from-an-array-and-return-as-not-nullable)

Comment: @Sinatr No, this answers different question.

Comment: @Sinatr Yet I agree that substituting `Where(x => x != null)` with `OfType` solves the issue, but the question remains valid.

Comment: This scenario is tracked at https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/37468